# If statement that gives incorrect output

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

This is my code:

```
if(weight<=5)
    cost=(2.8*weight);
if(weight<=20)
    cost=(2.8*5)+(5.2*(weight-5));
if(weight<=50)
    cost=(2.8*5)+(5.2*15)+(7*(weight-20));
if(weight>50)
    cost=(2.8*5)+(5.2*15)+(7*30)+(8.6*(weight-50));
```

when weight is lesser than 6.9, why is the answer all negative?

Comment: Welcome on S.O. please add your programming language tag. I suppose, as example, you use a Java environment

Comment: because it hits the third if <= 50, to prevent , extend the ifs eg. if(weight <=50 && weight >20)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping an "If Else Statement" java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937994/looping-an-if-else-statement-java)

Comment: Please add what is the result you expected to get, and what is the actual result. It is unclear from the question.

Comment: My suggestion: grab a pen and paper and step through your code by hand.

Answer (score 2):

when you write an `IF` nested statement, you must use the `ELSE` statement to prevent your scenario.

The right code:

```
if(weight<=5) {
    cost=(2.8*weight);
} else if(weight<=20) {
    cost=(2.8*5)+(5.2*(weight-5));
} else if(weight<=50) {
    cost=(2.8*5)+(5.2*15)+(7*(weight-20));
} else if(weight>50) {
    cost=(2.8*5)+(5.2*15)+(7*30)+(8.6*(weight-50));
}
```

In alternative, you must defined better your ranges, as follow:

```
if(weight<=5) {
    cost=(2.8*weight);
} if(weight > 5 && weight<=20) {
    cost=(2.8*5)+(5.2*(weight-5));
} if(weight > 20 && weight<=50) {
    cost=(2.8*5)+(5.2*15)+(7*(weight-20));
} if(weight>50) {
    cost=(2.8*5)+(5.2*15)+(7*30)+(8.6*(weight-50));
}
```